# Why HttpClient.Post method is not Executing all the Methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here I wrote small function as

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
//Here im Calling one Private Methode 
      GetValiedSession("22");
if(1==1{
}
else
//SomeCode
```

**GetValiedSession**

```
 public async Task<bool> GetValiedSession(string _SesToken)
        {
            string Baseurl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Baseurl"];
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
          { "securityToken","_SesToken"},
                          };
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
        var _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
 var content = new StringContent(_json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await client.PostAsync(Baseurl + "validate/session", content);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return false;
            }
```

on the above code

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(Baseurl + "validate/session", content);
```

after this code its Executing `if(1==1){---}`

Please guide me how can I stop that until its execute.

Comment: my minus may i know

Comment: put await on GetValiedSession("22");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Sync method to async If you can (This means you need to change your base method) and put change `GetValiedSession("22");` to `await GetValiedSession("22");`

```
public override async Task OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{

    //Here im Calling one Private Methode 
    await GetValiedSession("22");
    if(1==1{
    }
    else
    //SomeCode

}
```

or simply use your method synchronously

```
GetValiedSession("22").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ...Could u please Help me where can i learn asyn and await all thing

Comment: check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). If my answer is helpful for you please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer